# use the same code to generate same graphs for other files at once

Tags: r

I've written out codes for one particular file, and now I want to generate the same kind of graphs and files for the rest of similar data files, I wrote commands as the following, however, it doesn't work... 
When I plugged in these codes, R produced only one plot for the file "eight", and it states my error(see below)
I have edited and checked my codes so many times but still couldn't figure out what's wrong with it...would you please help me?

I really really appreciate your help!

```
my.files <- list.files()
for (i in 1: length(my.files)) {
temp.dat <- read.csv(my.files[i])
eight <- read.csv(file="8.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
eightout <- subset(eight, inout=="Outgoing from panel hh" & o_duration>0, select=c(inout, enc_callee, o_duration))
f <- function(eightoutf) nrow(eightoutf)
eightnocalls <- ddply(eightout,.(enc_callee),f)
colnames(eightnocalls)[2] <- "nocalls"
eightout$nocalls <- eightnocalls$nocalls [match(eightout$enc_callee, eightnocalls$enc_callee)]
eightout=data.frame(eightout,"time"=c(1:nrow(eightout)))
M <- plot(eightout$time,eightout$nocalls)
pdf(paste(Sys.Date(),"_",my.files[i],"_.pdf", sep=""))
plot(temp.dat$time, temp.dat$nocalls, main=my.files[i])
dev.off() }
```

This is what R says
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: see my comment below about trouble-shooting.  It's impossible to debug this without a reproducible example, and very frustrating to try to debug remotely.  Your code doesn't actually make much sense to me, since it reads `temp.dat` but then doesn't appear to use it for any of the subsequent manipulations.  I'm afraid I'm out of time and patience for this one ... sorry ...

Answer (score 2):

Try inserting `dev.off()` after your `plot` command ... ?  (If you want a bunch of separate files.   If you one want one big file of plots, then open your PDF file before you start the loop and close it after the end of the loop.)

Trying again with a cleaned-up version of code above.

```
my.files <- list.files("/E/Data")
for (i in seq_along(my.files)) {
  temp.dat <- read.csv(my.files[i])
   seven <- subset(alldata, aserno==7, select=c(I,C,D),
                     I=="o" & D>0)
   sevennumber <- ddply(sevenout,.(C), nrow)
   colnames(sevennumber)[2] <- "number"
   sevenout$number <- sevennumber$number[match(sevenout$C,sevennumber$C)]
   sevenout$time <- seq(nrow(sevenout))
   pdf(paste(Sys.Date(), my.files[i], "M.pdf", sep="_"))
   with(sevenout,plot(time, number, main=my.files[i])
   dev.off()  ## CLOSE pdf
   write.csv(sevenout,paste(Sys.Date(),
       my.files[i],"new_data.pdf”,sep="_"), row.names=FALSE)
}
```

Remaining weirdnesses/questions:

- `tmp.datout` is referred to but not defined.  Should it have been `sevenout`?
- the plot was made with `type="n"`, which would have led to an empty plot frame. ???
- I'm assuming that the manipulations are correct, since I can't reconstruct them.
- if in doubt try setting `i <- 1` and execute the code within your loop manually to see what happens ...

Comment: No...it doesn't work...R says"Error in dev.off (): One device can not be closed (invalid device)"

Comment: +1 I didn't realize it would push them all to a paginated file... thanks for that.

Comment: @user, it's because you had a device open already. Type dev.off() until you've closed them all. Then run it again

Comment: @ Brandon Bertelsen Sorry, I don't quite get it...What do you mean that I had a device open? what should I close? I only opened R once...(I'm new to R, so thank you very much for your patience!)

Comment: Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device) ?? What does it mean?

Comment: It means you didn't have any graphics devices open and then asked R to shut off the current graphics device.  Try closing R, starting a fresh session, and running the code above **with dev.off() inserted after the plot(...) command** as suggested above ...

Comment: My money is on Brandon being right, sounds like you've lost track of your graphics device windows. Insert the dev.off() after the plot line, save your code, close your session. Re open, load your data and run your function/loop.

Comment: @Ben, @nzcoops, thank you both for the help:) but some new problems occurred and I don't understand why..I've tried and edited so many times but still couldn't figure out. I would be very grateful if you could have a look at my edited question. Thank you!